# Draggable is not fit into droppable when dragged back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am new to the Draggable and Droppable plugin. Here the codepen lin of my app http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEMVwE

This is how it works,
     1.  We can drag the div element (Blue color) with in the `<td>` tag.
     2. We can place two div in the same row by drag and drop and the second
    div will be colored to red.

Here my problem, when I drag back the `div` (red color) to any empty column its `left` attribute is not changing. It is not fit into the row it goes outside of the row.

the `drop` and `drag` classes must be in position relative and absolute respectively please don't change that.

Please help me, it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMvZb)

In your code, change your `handleCardDrop()` function like this:

```
function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {   
    if( $(this).children('.drag').length <2){
            $(ui.draggable).css({"top": "1px" ,"left":  0 }).appendTo(this);
            var apptValue = dataAppt.attr("data-appt");
            apptValue -= 1;
            dataAppt.attr("data-appt", apptValue);
            if( ($(this).attr("data-appt")) == 1){
                 $(this).attr("data-appt","2");
            }
            else{
                $(this).attr("data-appt","1");
            }
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false ); // move this outside the if/else so it gets applied in all cases
            resetAppointment();
            }
    else{
        alert('Only Two allowed!!!');   
    }

 }
```

Also, change your `resetAppointment()` function like this:

```
function resetAppointment(){
    $('td[data-appt="2"] .drag').css("width", "45%"); // 45% not 50% since your full witdh elements are only 90% not 100%
    var width = $('td[data-appt="2"] .drag').first().width();
    $('td[data-appt="2"] .drag').last().css({"left": width}); // wrap your selector string with single quotes and use double quotes inside where needed so you dont have to escape the quotes
    $('td[data-appt="1"] div.drag').css({"width": "90%", "left" : "0px"}); // i use px explicitly here because if I dont, I'll always forget to add it later when I change this to 10 or something
}
```

Comment: But `$(this).draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );` this should be` true` i forget to enter  `$(this).draggable( 'option', 'revert', false ); `this code in the else part of handleDrop() function...

Comment: Ah, yep, moving `ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );`  outside the if/else so it gets applied in all cases fixes the issue. I updated the example and my answer. Glad it helped  : )